# Unable to import classes from maven dependency of dynamic web project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I converted a dynamic web project into a maven project by right-clicking on the project and choosing Configure -> Convert to Maven Project. I added below dependency jar in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Then,  right clicked project -> Run as -> maven install. The installation was successful.

Now all the jars and classes are available under the Maven Dependencies section.
Below is screenshot of my project structure.

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV4df.png)

Below is the screenshot of maven dependency section.

[Maven dependencies section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q24w3.png)

However, I am unable to import any package or class form the dependency jars into any of my Java class (Ex: HttpServices.java) in src folder. I am unable to use the jars although they are downloaded.

I tried updating Maven project (Force clearing snapshots), clean project, build project but nothing worked. I have no errors in the project. Also, when I added the jars directly into the build path (using add external jars i.e without maven) it worked perfectly fine. Please help in resolving the problem.

Note: Other Java-maven projects are working fine. Problem is only with this converted maven project.
I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Photon Release (4.8.0) and jdk 8

Below is the generated pom.xml. Compiler and war plugins were automatically generated when I converted the project to maven. I only added the dependency.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>executeAutomation</groupId>
  <artifactId>executeAutomation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Below is the class path entry for maven.

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
```

Comment: Because of `<scope>test</scope>` everything of this dependency is available only in test source, not in the main source. Does removing `<scope>test</scope>` and right-click the project and _Maven > Update Project..._ fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Because of **`<scope>test</scope>`** everything of this dependency is **available only in test source**, not in the main source.

**Remove `<scope>test</scope>`**, right-click the project and choose ***Maven > Update Project...***.

More about classpath separation for test sources in Eclipse:

- [Eclipse Photon (4.8) - New and Noteworthy - Test sources](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/jdt.php#jdt-test-sources)
- [Short video showing classpath separation for Maven in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-ZTkhek5TU&t=218s)